# sql query to return 0 instead of NULL

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have the following statement, and it works fine, except for the fact that if, the 2nd table has no reference items to the first table it will return no results.

What I need is it to return `count(p.match_id) AS matchcount` as 0

```
"SELECT c.*, count(p.match_id) AS matchcount 
    FROM ci_address_book c LEFT JOIN ci_matched_sanctions p
    ON c.id = p.addressbook_id 
    GROUP BY p.addressbook_id ORDER BY c.id LIMIT ".$offset.",".$num;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem here is that you're using a `LEFT JOIN`. This means that all rows in `c` will be returned even if they don't match the rows in `p`.

Your problem.

> if the 2nd table has no reference items to the first table it will return no results

Let me rephrase this in my own words.

> if the **p** table has no reference items to the **c** table it will not return any results

When you do a LEFT JOIN, anything in the "right" table that is empty will come back with values of NULL. So matchcount is going to be "NULL" in these cases. (you can tests this by doing `select c.*, p.* ... where p.addressbook_id = NULL`)

To display a "0" instead you do the following:

`SELECT c.*, COALESCE(COUNT(p.match_id), 0) AS matchcount`

`COALESCE` returns the first non-NULL value. So when COUNT(p.match_id) is NULL, you get 0.

Comment: partially true... my statement {"SELECT c.*, COALESCE(COUNT(p.match_id), 0) AS matchcount FROM ci_address_book c LEFT OUTER JOIN ci_matched_sanctions p ON c.id = p.addressbook_id GROUP BY p.addressbook_id ORDER BY c.id LIMIT ".$offset.",".$num;} ... this will give me only the amount of results back as much as I have in the matched_sanctions table. My addressbooktable has 80 names now. if matched_sanctions has no row at all, I get nothing. if it has 1, i get 1, if it has 2 i get 2 etc...

Comment: maybe rephrase my q. I have a table with names (addressbook) and I have a table which contains matches. Referred to by the id. so it is a 1-many relation. I would like to count the number of rows in the matched table while I get all the results of addressbook. So i would like to see : addressbook_id:1 - name - count

Comment: SELECT c.*, IFNULL(p.total, 0) num FROM ci_address_book c LEFT JOIN (SELECT addressbook_id,COUNT(*) AS total FROM ci_matched_sanctions GROUP BY addressbook_id) AS p ON c.id=p.addressbook_id did the trick

Comment: Yep, that also makes sense, count first and then join.